# Is there a pattern whereby a subclass guarantees it will call certain methods?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

Is there a pattern, or structure that guarantees that a subclass will, at a certain stage in it's life cycle will either **call** certain methods?

I'm looking for something *similar* to when a class implements a certain interface, it is essentially saying that it promises to implement certain methods.

**Anti Pattern?** I understand that this may be in-fact some sort of antipattern. I basically need to a sanity check that a collection of subclasses are doing the work they should be doing. If nothing exists, I'll simply write a mini file parser that will do a quick check that the methods are called.

This question is language agnostic, but in this case I'm using C#

Comment: Sounds like what you want are some unit tests.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I've tried to clarify the question a tad

Comment: @Ghopper21 True, and perhaps that's what I need to look at. I'm working within the Unity3D framework, and unsure how supported it is. We shall see

Comment: Incidentally, I think the Unity3D folks just released an integrated testing framework. Worth checking out.

Comment: @Ghopper21 I can't find any info on integrated testing. There are a few to be found on github via independently developed solutions.

Comment: Here you go: http://blogs.unity3d.com/2013/12/18/unity-test-tools-released/

Comment: @Ghopper21 How'd I not know about that! Very cool, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible, just by design. I mean, a superclass doesn't know anything about its subclasses, so I don't see how this could be.

Now, when you talk about *life cycle*, it might be possible that you have some sort of `start()` and `stop()` methods? If so, why not having another method in the superclass, say `finalCheck()` that cannot be overriden in a subclass and that checks whether your methods have been called or not, maybe just using some `bool` class fields. I know this would not guarantee anything, but at least it could be checked at runtime.

In any case, and without any further info, it just looks like a need to redesign something. For instance, instead of this:

```
abstract class Parent {
    void mustDo1() { }
    void mustDo2() { }
    abstract void do() { }
}

class Child : Parent {
    override void do() {
        base.mustDo1(); // force ?
        // something custom
        base.mustDo2(); // force ?
    }
}
```

try to come up with something like this:

```
abstract class Parent {
    void mustDo1() { }
    void mustDo2() { }
    void do() {
        this.mustDo1();
        this.customDo();
        this.mustDo2();
    }
    abstract void customDo() { }
}

class Child : Parent {
    override void customDo() {
        // something custom
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You question is not 100% clear, but I assume the first sentence is what you're really looking for:

> Is there a pattern, or structure that guarantees that a subclass will,
>   at a certain stage in it's life cycle will either call certain
>   methods, or send certain messages?

I know nothing about that.

You can make the base class `abstract`, force all subclasses to implement certain methods by making the methods `abstract` and implement the calls depending on object state and lifecycle in the base class. Calling these `abstract` methods from base class will invoke their implementations from subclass.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand how there could be one. A subclass can do anything it wants. You should implement those certain method calls in a base class to be sure, and make them non-virtual so they cannot even be overridden. Something similar can be achieved if you put events in the interface. You can't guarantee that the implementer will trigger them, but if they are triggered, they will call out to wherever you want.

Comment: Cool. I am completely happy with the answer being "no, it's not possible"

Answer (score 3):

You can't guarantee that any method will call specific methods, and it's advisable to try to redesign your system so that this is not necessary... but if you have to there are things you can do to make it clear to future programmers that they need to:

- In many cases you can implement virtual methods which are called at appropriate moments in your algorithm when the derived class needs to do something (e.g. serialize some data). The base class can often provide a default implementation that can be used in most cases so the derived class only has to override these methods occasionally.Or the method can be abstract or throw an exception to force the derived class to implement it. Using this approach you get inversion of control so the base class tells the derived class what to do and when.
- provide helper methods that call these required methods for you, so instead of having to write 3 or 4 lines of code, the programmer writing a derived class only has to call DoImportantThingNow(); - this makes it easier to remember to make the call, easier to get the call right, and easier to see that this bit of code is important to the correct operation of your system.
- Add verification code to your bsse class. it may be able to check that certain methods have been called when expected, and throw an exception if a derived class has not kept its part of the bargain.
- Add good documentation comments to make it clear what is expected if you override a virtual method.

Essentially, if you need another programmer to do something special to extend your code, you need to make it s simple and foolproof as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, thats not possible, the main reason being that a superclass doesn't know anything about its subclasses